# Loop to run multiple updates from different tables in postgres

Tags: function, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I am running Postgres 9.1 and have a master table (`returns.msf_mse`) with 30 empty columns and 30 additional temporary tables (`temp23_01` - `temp23_30`). I want to populate each of the empty columns in the master table with the data from a particular column from each temporary table. The relevant column in each temporary table is always `cumret_past`.

I have tried to create a stored procedure/function to achieve this and have been getting nowhere. I have also tried to loop over the update statement but can not get it to work. My base query is:

```
update returns.msf_mse as a
set cumret_past_23_01 = b.cumret_past  
from temp23_01 as b
where a.date = b.date
and a.permno = b.permno;
```

I simply want to run this statement 30 times, incrementing `cumret_past_23_i` and `temp23_i` each time.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's a decent question. Got job for a first post. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [**`DO`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-do.html) statement (pg 9.0+) with [`EXECUTE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) to loop through all tables:

```
DO
$$
BEGIN

FOR i IN 1..30 LOOP
    EXECUTE '
    UPDATE returns.msf_mse a
    SET    cumret_past_23_' || to_char(i, 'FM00') || ' = b.cumret_past  
    FROM   temp23_' || to_char(i, 'FM00') || ' b
    WHERE  a.date = b.date
    AND    a.permno = b.permno';
END LOOP;

END
$$
```

Pay attention to the leading space when formatting the number with [`to_char()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html). I use the `FM` modifier to get rid of it.

Aside: I wouldn't use `date` as column name, it easily conflicts with the base type or the function of the same name.

Comment: Thanks Erwin. This is a huge help!